# jquery live focus blur

Tags: jquery

How can I do a blur and focus method in jQuery "on" method, focus is working perfect, blur isn't how can I do this?

I have tried:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.activityLikeButton', function(){
    // works
});

$(document).on('blur', '.activityLikeButton', function(){
    // does not work
});
```

as the comments say, the focus is working perfect, the blur isn't.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What goes inside the `//does not work` part?

Comment: alert if you want or console log? what ever its just not working.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the full code. Whatever you've posted works ideally.

Comment: It works fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Mvvb/4/ what browser are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with alerts and it didn't work. However, when I set a value for the textbox, on which I am using the focus and blur, it worked for me too.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('focus', '.box', function(){
    $(this).val('hgfvs');
   });

   $(document).on('blur', '.box', function(){
    $(this).val('');
   });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="box" />
```